# jquery conditional form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update user profile. After user inserts his address and submits it converts it to latitude and longitude. I created a conditional statement: if GeocoderStatus is OK then change geoLocationOK = 1 else it is 0. When it is 1 then run the update function, but the latitude and longitude is not passed to formData. On second update click it is added. Any suggestion how can I include the latitude and longitude in formData?

### Click to update

```
        $(document).on("click", "#updateProfile", function (e) {
            function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        console.log(latitude);
                        console.log(longitude);
                        userLatitude = document.getElementById('cityLat').value = latitude;
                        userLongitude = document.getElementById('cityLng').value = longitude;
                        geoLocationOK = 1;
                        console.log(geoLocationOK);

                    } else {
                        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }
            geocodeAddress(geocoder);

            if(geoLocationOK == 1){
                updateProfile();
            }else{
                console.log("not ok");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

This is the update function

```
            function updateProfile(){
                console.log(geoLocationOK);

                $('#rootwizard').formValidation({
                    framework: 'bootstrap',
                    excluded: [':disabled'],
                    icon: {
                        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                    },   
                    live: 'enabled',

                    framework: 'bootstrap',
                    icon: {
                        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        userPhoneNr: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Please insert phone nr'
                                },
                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
                                    message: 'Error'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }).on('success.form.fv', function(e, data) {
                    // Prevent form submission
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var $form    = $(e.target),
                        formData = new FormData(),
                        params   = $form.serializeArray(),
                        files    = $form.find('[name="userProfilePhoto"]')[0].files;



                    $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                        formData.append(val.name, val.value);
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $form.attr('action'),
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            if(data.status == 'success'){

                                getProfileData();     
                            }    
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
                            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
                        }
                    });
                    // Now Destroy
                    function destroyFormValidation() {
                        var instance = $('#rootwizard').data('formValidation');
                        if (instance) {
                            instance.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                    destroyFormValidation();
                });
            }
```

Comment: This is very insecure, I would decide server-side if a profile gets updated.

Comment: @Robert there is server side verification as well.

Comment: `geocoder.geocode()` is async. So set relevant logic in method callback.

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you for the reply. Can you give any example, since feels like I have tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: You should call `updateProfile();` from geocoder.geocode() callback.

Comment: @A.Wolff  tried and it gives me this Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'lat' and the latitude and longitude are not passed in formdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you only can update on the second click is because on the first click you actually binding the form validation. Why not bind the form validation separately outside the function  *updateProfile* .

And then inside  *updateProfile*  submit the form:

```
function updateProfile(){
     $('#rootwizard').submit();
}
```

Comment: what if I am using ajax?

Comment: Wouldn't that be handled by the form validation callback: on('success.form.fv', function(e, data)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
        if(geoLocationOK == 1){
            updateProfile();
        }else{
            console.log("not ok");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

and move the call to

```
updateProfile();
```

inside your

```
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { ... }
```

block.

You maybe also still need `e.preventDefault();` in there somewhere as well (or you could change the `updateProfile` element to not be a submit button).

It looks like the geolocation function is asynchronous, which means it it executed in parallel to the other code. Therefore your `if (geolocationOK == 1)` is almost certain going to run before the function which sets the geolocationOK variable.

In any situation like this with async calls, if you have code which depends on the results of the async call, then that call must be executed within the "success" context of the async call.

Comment: the latitude and longitude are still not getting passed for some reason.